# Where to do the CASTING in SQL PIVOT Expression

Tags: sql-server, casting, sum, pivot

I am using the below SQL query and use pivoting to interchange rows and cols in the SELECT result.

> Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

(Value) col -> DataType-> VARCHAR(256) -> PartyRelationshipSetting Table

I am unable change the datatype in the table because it's a multivalued column and I need to convert the value into INT or relevant datatype to perform the `SUM` operation used in the below PIVOT expression.

```
SELECT PartyRelationshipID,[2] AS OrderGroup,[3] AS TaxStatus,[4] AS Area
FROM (SELECT PartyRelationshipID,PartyRelationshipSettingTypeID,Value FROM [Party].PartyRelationshipSetting prs) AS SourceTable
INNER JOIN Party.PartyRelationship prship ON SourceTable.PartyRelationshipID = prship.ID
PIVOT
(
SUM(Value)
FOR PartyRelationshipSettingTypeID IN ([2],[3],[4])
)AS PivotTable
```

I tried the below methods. But it gives me a syntax error.

1)

```
CAST(Value FROM [Party].PartyRelationshipSetting prs)AS INT) AS SourceTable
```

2)

```
PIVOT
(
SUM(CAST(Value AS INT))
FOR PartyRelationshipSettingTypeID IN ([2],[3],[4])
)AS PivotTable
```

How to cast this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the conversion in the inner query itself

```
SELECT PartyRelationshipID,
       [2] AS OrderGroup,
       [3] AS TaxStatus,
       [4] AS Area
FROM   (SELECT PartyRelationshipID,
               PartyRelationshipSettingTypeID,
               Value = Cast(Value AS INT) --here
        FROM   [Party].PartyRelationshipSetting prs) AS SourceTable
       INNER JOIN Party.PartyRelationship prship
               ON SourceTable.PartyRelationshipID = prship.ID
PIVOT(SUM(Value) FOR PartyRelationshipSettingTypeID IN ([2],[3],[4]))AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Thanks, @ரதீப். +1 
I need your help for this as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374723/the-column-id-was-specified-multiple-times-for-pivottable